Lottie animation doesn't look correct on Flutter and appears to be glitched?
so recently i got this problem that no matter what i do the lottie animation won't look right in my flutter app, i tried IOS & Android Physical Devices but still the same results:

here is the link to the original file:
https://lottiefiles.com/free-animation/light-to-dark-mode-switch-xDBlEV73X2?from=search
here is my code:
Lottie.asset(
            'assets/lottie/anim_test.json',
            frameRate: FrameRate.max,
          ),


Lottie's original animation works well for me. Maybe it could be the animation file, it seems that it only has 2 frames because it is a custom file. Unfortunately, the Lottie editor does not have full capabilities for editing the animations. Use Adobe After Effects in this cases

Step 1:-
Add Pubspec.yaml in below line
  assets:
    - assets/animation.json

Step 2:-
Replace Lottie.asset Line
Lottie.asset('assets/animation.json',frameRate: FrameRate.max,)
Example:-
class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Lottie.asset('assets/animation.json',frameRate: FrameRate.max,),
      ),
    );
  }
}

